# Using fetch for React API callback using Google Books- books.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, google-api, google-books

I am working with React and the Google Books API to create a web app. I want books to be searchable via the google books API. When my fetch request hits the google books API, I am getting a successful return but the callback is not parsing the JSON and I am getting the error: "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): books.map is not a function" resulting from my component that is intended to show the results of a search. The problem seems to be exclusively between the fetch request and the HandleSearchChange function within the component where the 'NewSearch.search' function is initiated and the state is set. The fetch request returns the data but it seems to stop there without parsing the response- the response is already returned in json- see https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=flo .

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the fetch request:

```js
function search(query, cb) {
  return fetch(`https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${query}`, {
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response)
    }
  })

  .then(checkStatus)
  .then(parseJSON)
  .then(cb);
}

function checkStatus(response) {
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
    return response;
  }
  const error = new Error(`HTTP Error ${response.statusText}`);
  error.status = response.statusText;
  error.response = response;
  console.log(error);
  throw error;
}

function parseJSON(response) {
  return response.json();
  return console.log(response.json())
}

const NewSearch = { search };
export default NewSearch;
```

Here is the component:

```js
import react from 'react';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import NewSearch from '../actions/NewSearch';

const MATCHING_ITEM_LIMIT = 25;

class SearchBooks extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        books: [],
        showRemoveIcon: false,
        searchValue: '',
      };

      this.handleSearchChange = this.handleSearchChange.bind(this);
    }

  handleSearchChange = (e) => {
    let value = e.target.value;

    if (this._isMounted) {
      this.setState({
        searchValue: value,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
      });
    }

    if (value === '') {
      this.setState({
        books: [],
        showRemoveIcon: false,
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        showRemoveIcon: true,
      });

      NewSearch.search(value, (books) => {
        this.setState({
          books: books
          //books: books.slice(0, MATCHING_ITEM_LIMIT),
        });
      });
    }
  };

  handleSearchCancel = () => {
    this.setState({
      books: [],
      showRemoveIcon: false,
      searchValue: '',
    });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false
  }

  render() {
    const { showRemoveIcon, books } = this.state;
    const removeIconStyle = showRemoveIcon ? {} : { visibility: 'hidden'};

    const bookRows = books.map((book, idx) =>(
      <tr>
      <td>{book.volumeInfo.title}</td>
      <td>{book.volumeInfo.authors[0]}</td>
      <td>{book.volumeInfo.description}</td>
      </tr>
    ));

    return (
      <div id='book-search'>
        <table className='ui selectable structured large table'>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th colSpan='5'>
                <div className='ui fluid search'>
                  <input
                  className='prompt'
                  type='text'
                  placeholder='Search books...'
                  value={this.state.searchValue}
                  onChange={this.handleSearchChange}
                  />
                  <i className='search icon' />
                </div>
                <i
                className='remove icon'
                onClick={this.handleSearchCancel}
                style={removeIconStyle}
                />
              </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th className='eight wide'>Title</th>
              <th>Authors</th>
              <th> Description</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        <tbody>
          {bookRows}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
 }
}

export default SearchBooks;
```

Comment: ```.map``` is an array method.  That error likely means whatever you're calling ```.map``` on isn't an array.

Answer (score 0):

Because your Json response is not the array.
You need to return response.items (or using console you can check what exactly you want, but it should be array) in checkStatus function. And then call callback function.

Comment: That did the trick- the json of the google books is nested and I wasn't properly accounting for that in either my fetch or my checkStatus. My many thanks!